# natural language corpus string to int

Tags: python, iteration, corpus

take a sample of sentences from each of the corpus1, corpus2 and corpus3 corpora and displays the average length (as measured in terms of the number of characters in the sentence).

so I've 3 corpus and sample_raw_sents is a defined function to return random sentences:

```
tcr = corpus1()
rcr = corpus2()
mcr = corpus3()  
sample_size=50
for sentence in tcr.sample_raw_sents(sample_size):
    print(len(sentence))
for sentence in rcr.sample_raw_sents(sample_size):
    print(len(sentence))
for sentence in mcr.sample_raw_sents(sample_size):
    print(len(sentence))
```

so using this code all lengths are printed, though how do I sum() these lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip`, it will allow you to draw a sentence from each corpus all at once.

```
tcr = corpus1()
rcr = corpus2()
mcr = corpus3()  
sample_size=50

zipped = zip(tcr.sample_raw_sents(sample_size),
             rcr.sample_raw_sents(sample_size),
             mcr.sample_raw_sents(sample_size))

for s1, s2, s3 in zipped:
    summed = len(s1) + len(s2) + len(s3)
    average = summed/3
    print(summed, average)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store all lengths of `sentences` in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and then sum them up.

```
tcr = corpus1()
rcr = corpus2()
mcr = corpus3()  
sample_size=50

lengths = []
for sentence in tcr.sample_raw_sents(sample_size):
    lengths.append(len(sentence))
for sentence in rcr.sample_raw_sents(sample_size):
    lengths.append(len(sentence))
for sentence in mcr.sample_raw_sents(sample_size):
    lengths.append(len(sentence))

print(sum(lengths) / len(lengths))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tcr = corpus1()
rcr = corpus2()
mcr = corpus3()  
sample_size=50
s = 0
for sentence in tcr.sample_raw_sents(sample_size):
    s = s + len(sentence)
for sentence in rcr.sample_raw_sents(sample_size):
    s = s + len(sentence)
for sentence in mcr.sample_raw_sents(sample_size):
    s = s + len(sentence)

average = s/150
print('average: {}'.format(average))
```